# Protein Intake did not work

Tags: weight-loss, fat

Past month , I increased my protein intake to 165 grams (I weigh 81 kgs , Male) ,I workout with weights and cardio at the end , and abs every alternate day , but today when I had my body measurements , there was no significant change , and whatever changes occured were negative.Although I am able to lift heavier than what I could one month back. What went wrong?[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to lose weight? And what body measurements were these, did you measure body fat?

Comment: This is unanswerable in the current condition. We don't know what you were trying to achieve, we don't know what your ***actual*** workout regimen is, or anything else about your diet.

Comment: I am trying to lose body fat and build some muscle and by measurements I mean , the size of arms , chest , shoulders , waist , etc.

Comment: There is still not enough information here to answer the question. What makes you think your protein intake is the problem?

Comment: @MohitSharma - Ok, so you want to increase strength and build muscle. Outline a weeks worth of workouts with weights for each exercise. I am betting that your protein intake is a very minor (if any) part of the lack of apparent progress.

Comment: Ok , so my total calories a day gets to a Max value of 2350 , and my workout basically is Monday - Chest and Running , Tuesday - Arms , Elliptical and abs , Wednesday -  Back and Cycle , Thursday - And and Running , Friday - Shoulders and Elliptical , Saturday - Legs , Cycle and Abs.

Comment: Mohit - you can edit your answer to include that. And it still needs more. Chest and running, what exercises? How much weight/sets/reps per exercise? How far/fast do you run? The more detail you can edit in, the better we can answer.

Comment: @JohnP I have added the workout only thing is I don't do Shoulder V Pushups and instead of deadlifts I do sumo squads. and set reps are 15 , 12 , 10.

Comment: Also I did cardio for 10 mins instead of 20 mins.

Answer (score 2):

The **most** important factor for most people trying to lose (or gain) weight is **total calorie intake**.

The ratio of protein to carbs and fats has some effect, but it's less than total calories.

In short: eating 165 grams of protein daily is fine.  If that's part of a 4000-calorie diet, you're probably going to gain weight.  If it's part of a 1200-calorie diet, you're probably going to lose weight.

If you've taken your regular diet and added in 165 calories of protein on top of it, you're almost certainly going to gain weight.

Feel free to describe your overall diet in more detail if you like.